# Visualizing augmented train images [tensorflow object detection api]

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard, object-detection-api, data-augmentation

It is possible to augment images in tensorflow object detection api config files, e.g.:

```
data_augmentation_options {
  random_horizontal_flip {
  }
}
data_augmentation_options {
  ssd_random_crop {
  }
}
```

**How can I visualize the training images to inspect the results of the augmentation?**

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Could you post full code?

Comment: What code are you interested in?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is the code to achieve what has been asked in the question https://github.com/majrie/visualize_augmentation/blob/master/visualize_augmentation.ipynb .

It is based on the answer of @danyfang.

Answer (score 4):

I suggest you look at [input_test.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/inputs_test.py) file, specifically the function `test_apply_image_and_box_augmentation` in class [`DataAugmentationFnTest`](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/8367cf6dabe11adf7628541706b660821f397dce/research/object_detection/inputs_test.py#L393). You can add the `data_augmentation_options` there and pass your image to the `tensor_dict`. To visualize it, you can call matplotlib function after sess.run() as `augmented_tensor_dict_out` can be passed as input argument.

Comment: Thank you that helped a lot. However, preprocessor.py is also normalizing the image. Can I disable it or restore the values before normalization and still keep the augmentation?

Comment: I've found in `https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/core/preprocessor_test.py` there exist test code for each individual augmentation option. I think this could fit your goal more precisely.