# Tensorflow, object detection API

Tags: object-detection-api

Is there a way to view the images that `tensorflow object detection api` trains on after all preprocessing/augmentation.

I'd like to verify that things look correctly. I was able to verify the resizing my looking at the graph post resize in inference but I obviously can't do that for augmentation options.

TIA

Answer (score 2):

I answered a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53890669/save-tensorflow-object-detection-augmented-images).

You can utilize the test script provided by the api and make some changes to fit your need.

I wrote a little test script called `augmentation_test.py`. It borrowed some code from [`input_test.py`](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/inputs_test.py)

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from __future__ import division
from __future__ import print_function

import functools
import os
from absl.testing import parameterized

import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from scipy.misc import imsave, imread

from object_detection import inputs
from object_detection.core import preprocessor
from object_detection.core import standard_fields as fields
from object_detection.utils import config_util
from object_detection.utils import test_case

FLAGS = tf.flags.FLAGS

class DataAugmentationFnTest(test_case.TestCase):

  def test_apply_image_and_box_augmentation(self):
    data_augmentation_options = [
        (preprocessor.random_horizontal_flip, {
        })
    ]
    data_augmentation_fn = functools.partial(
        inputs.augment_input_data,
        data_augmentation_options=data_augmentation_options)
    tensor_dict = {
        fields.InputDataFields.image:
            tf.constant(imread('lena.jpeg').astype(np.float32)),
        fields.InputDataFields.groundtruth_boxes:
            tf.constant(np.array([[.5, .5, 1., 1.]], np.float32))
    }
    augmented_tensor_dict = 
        data_augmentation_fn(tensor_dict=tensor_dict)
    with self.test_session() as sess:
      augmented_tensor_dict_out = sess.run(augmented_tensor_dict)
    imsave('lena_out.jpeg',augmented_tensor_dict_out[fields.InputDataFields.image])


if __name__ == '__main__':
  tf.test.main()
```

You can put this script under `models/research/object_detection/` and simply run it with `python augmentation_test.py` (Of course you need to install the API first). To successfully run it you should provide any image name 'lena.jpeg' and the output image after augmentation would be saved as 'lena_out.jpeg'.

I ran it with the 'lena' image and here is the result before augmentation and after augmentation.
[image: lena]

[image: lena_out].

Note that I used `preprocessor.random_horizontal_flip` in the script. And the result showed exactly what the input image looks like after `random_horizontal_flip`. To test it with other augmentation options, you can replace the `random_horizontal_flip` with other methods (which are all defined in [preprocessor.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/core/preprocessor.py)), all you can append other options to the `data_augmentation_options` list, for example:

```
data_augmentation_options = [(preprocessor.resize_image, {
        'new_height': 20,
        'new_width': 20,
        'method': tf.image.ResizeMethod.NEAREST_NEIGHBOR
    }),(preprocessor.random_horizontal_flip, {
    })]
```